# How to prove that there exists a $B$ such that $A=B^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

> If matrix $A$ is such that $A+A^T$ is a positive definite matrix, show that there exists a $B$ such that $A=B^2$, where $B+B^T$ is a positive definite matrix.

My try: since $A+A^T$ is positive matrix, then exists $Q$ such
$$Q^{-1}(A+A^T)Q=diag(a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n})$$
where $a_{i}>0$, $i=1,2,\cdots,n$
then I can't，Thank you

Comment: It says a lot about the relation between being positive definite and having the symmetric part positive definite here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PositiveDefiniteMatrix.html

Comment: Only no proof are given there. Actually the statements there solve your question. It states that a matrix $A$ is positive definite iff $\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$ is positive definite. Also it states that any positive definite matrix has exactly one positive definite square root. These two combined solves the problem.

Comment: Also note that you cannot necessarily diagonalize your matrix. Being positive definite does NOT imply being diagonalizable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in String’s comment, it suffices to show the property claimed
in the Wolfram link, i.e. a real matrix $A$ is positive definite if
and only if the symmetric part $S=\frac{A+A^T}{2}$ is positive definite.

We have for any vector $X$,

$$
(SX|X)=\frac{1}{2}.\bigg( (AX|X)+(A^TX|X)\bigg)=
\frac{1}{2}.\bigg( (AX|X)+(X|AX)\bigg)=(AX|X)
$$

so that the equivalence is clear.